# Can I use getComponents() instead of keeping an ArrayList of components?

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jpanel, jcomponent

I have an app where a user can dynamically add shapes, let's say a Circle (for simplicity), by clicking on a location (x,y).  I have been keeping an ArrayList of Circles so they are re-added to the JPanel via the paintComponent() method, however I suspect that this might be redundant given that there is a behind the scenes array being kept, which can be retrieved via the built-in getComponents() method.  Am I right?  The key parts of my code is below:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements Constants {
Point point;
Figure figure;

public DrawingPanel() {
    point = new Point(0, 0);
    figure = new Circle(point, defaultSize);
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
    addMouseListener(new ActionHandler());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
    super.paintComponent(page);
    add(figure);
    }

private class ActionHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mousePressed(e);
        Point point = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("Mouse pressed at (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");

        String figureState = itemHandler.getFigureState();
        String figureActionState = itemHandler.getFigureActionState();

        if (figureActionState.equals("None")) {
            switch (figureState) {
                case "Circle" -> {
                    figure = new Circle(point, defaultSize);
                    figure.setBounds((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY(), 50, 50);
                    figure.addMouseListener(new ActionHandler());
                }
                case "Square" -> {
                    figure = new Rect(point, defaultSize);
                    figure.setBounds((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY(), 50, 50);
                    figure.addMouseListener(new ActionHandler());
                }
                case "Cross" -> {
                    figure = new Cross(point, defaultSize);
                    figure.setBounds((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY(), 50, 50);
                    figure.addMouseListener(new ActionHandler());
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Figure extends JComponent {
Point position;
Dimension size;

public Figure(Point position, Dimension size) {
    this.position = position;
    this.size = size;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
    super.paintComponent(page);
}
```

}

```
public interface Constants {
ItemHandler itemHandler = new ItemHandler();
Dimension defaultSize = new Dimension(50, 50);
```

}

Comment: The container getComponents method returns an array of Swing components, like JLabel, JButton, etc.  You're keeping a List of Figure instances, where a Figure should be an instance of a plain Java getter / setter class.  Since you didn't post the code, I have no idea what a Figure is.

Comment: *"The key parts of my code is below:"* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). **BTW:** While using `getComponents` might be a possibility, it is not good programming practice. Keep a (separate) reference to the components of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've updated the code to include the figure class.  Also, I had not realised, but suspected, that I don't need to re keep track of all the Objects added to a Panel; that paintComponent takes care of this.  I've re-added my adjusted code that seems to be doing what I intended now.

Comment: *but suspected, that I don't need to re keep track of all the Objects added to a Panel; that paintComponent takes care of this* No. All the paintComponent() method does is paint a single component. The logic for a JLabel will be different than the logic for a JButton. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: @PaulRichardLewis, Your updated logic is still wrong. Did you not read my answer? You should NOT be adding components to the panel in the paintComponent() method. Add the component to the panel when you create the component. In fact, there is no need to override the paintComponent() method of the JPanel if you are simple attempting to add components to the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overall design issues:

1. A painting method should NOT change the state of the class. The painting method should only paint the current state of the class. Therefore you should NOT be adding components to the panel in the paintComponent() method.
2. I don't see a reason to keep the two ArrayLists. The component should know how to paint itself and contain all the necessary information to paint itself.

Maybe instead of using an actual components you can just paint a `Shape`. Check out [Drag a Painted Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape). It keeps an ArrayList of all the `Shapes` to be painted. This ArrayList is used to identify a `Shape` that you want to drag. You would need to replace the drag logic with your existing mouse handling logic.