# How can I change the background color by pressing left and right arrow keys from keyboard? (Not inside the clock,outside the clock)

Tags: java, swing

I'm quite new to java programming and I found this code mainly from the internet but edited it a bit. I think the code works fine. It displays the current time and its hands changing correctly. I want to change the background color by using a second class.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;  
import java.awt.Font;  
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.Locale;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Clock extends JPanel implements Runnable  {  
 
Thread thread = null;   
  int xcenter = 175;
  int ycenter = 175;
 
 private void drawStructure(Graphics g) { 
      
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
        g.setFont(new Font("Italic", Font.ITALIC, 25)); 
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
        g.drawOval(xcenter- 150, ycenter - 150, 300, 300); 
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(xcenter-150,  ycenter-150,300, 300);
        
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("9",xcenter- 145,  ycenter + 0);  
        g.drawString("3",xcenter + 135,  ycenter + 0);  
        g.drawString("12",xcenter - 10, ycenter - 130);  
        g.drawString("6", xcenter- 10, ycenter + 145);      
 }  
 public void paint(Graphics g)    {
  
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  drawStructure(g);
  
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    
    int xksaniye =  now.getSecond();
    int yksaniye = now.getSecond();
    int xkdakika = now.getMinute();
    int ykdakika = now.getMinute(); 
    int xksaat =   now.getHour();
    int yksaat =   now.getHour();
    
    xksaniye = (int) (Math.cos(now.getSecond() * 3.14f / 30 - 3.14f / 2) * 120 +  xcenter); 
    yksaniye = (int)(Math.sin(now.getSecond() * 3.14f / 30 - 3.14f / 2) * 120 + ycenter);  
    xkdakika = (int)(Math.cos(now.getMinute() * 3.14f / 30 - 3.14f / 2) * 100 +  xcenter);  
    ykdakika = (int)(Math.sin(now.getMinute() * 3.14f / 30 - 3.14f / 2) * 100 + ycenter);  
    xksaat = (int)(Math.cos((now.getHour() * 30 + now.getMinute() / 2) * 3.14f / 180 - 3.14f / 2) * 80 +  xcenter);  
    yksaat = (int)(Math.sin(( now.getHour() * 30 + now.getMinute() / 2) * 3.14f / 180 - 3.14f / 2) * 80 + ycenter); 
 
         g.setColor(Color.magenta); 
         g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
         g.drawLine(xcenter, ycenter,xksaniye, yksaniye);  
  
         g.setColor(Color.red);
         g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
         g.drawLine(xcenter, ycenter - 1,xkdakika, ykdakika);  
         g.drawLine(xcenter - 1, ycenter, xkdakika,ykdakika);
  
         g.setColor(Color.green); 
         g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
         g.drawLine(xcenter, ycenter - 1, xksaat, yksaat);  
         g.drawLine(xcenter - 1, ycenter,xksaat,yksaat);      
 } 
 
 public void start()   {  
  if (thread == null)   {  
   thread = new Thread(this);  
   thread.start();  
   }  
 }  
 
 public void stop()   {  
  thread = null;  
 }  
 public void run()   {  
  while (thread != null) {  
   try  {  
    Thread.sleep(100);  
    }   
   catch (InterruptedException e) {}  
   repaint();  
   }  
  thread = null;  
 }  
 
 public void update(Graphics g){  
  paint(g);  
 } 
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
          JFrame f = new JFrame("Analog Saat Pojesi");
          
           f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           f.getContentPane().add(new Clock());
           f.setBounds(0, 0, 370, 400);
           Clock clock = new Clock();  
           f.add(clock); 
           f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           f.setVisible(true);
           clock.start();
           Clock saat = new Clock();    
    }
}
```

And you see here my second class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ChangeColor extends JPanel{
    
    public  ChangeColor(){
        addKeyListener(new DirectionListener());
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }

    private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks from now on for the answers. As I said I want to change the background, not the color of the inside of the clock.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the background color by using a second class.

That is not how Swing works. KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component that has focus.

What do you plan to do with with your ChangeColor class? You can't it it to the frame since it doesn't do anything.

Instead all you need is the DirectionListener class. It should be part of your Clock class. Then in the constructor of your Clock class you create an instance of the DirectionListener class and add it as the KeyListener to the Clock class.

Other issues:

1. Don't override paint(). Instead when using Swing you override paintComponent(...).
2. Don't override update(). Get rid of that code that is something that is done with AWT and is not necessary when using Swing

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

First make the above change to clean up the painting logic.

Then you can do the following to better implement Swing coding practices:

1. Don't use a Thread. Updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Instead you should be using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
2. Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

I suggest you keep a link to the Swing tutorial handy. I have provided links to 3 sections. Most of your code seems to be based on old AWT coding practices. Use the `Swing tutorial` as your reference for Swing.

Also, you have variables for each of the second, minute and hour values. So use them. Don't keep invoking the method. It makes your code comfusing as people will wonder why you create the variable and never use it.

In fact why do you even have multiple variables for each of the above methods. You should only have a single variable for each value.

As a tip you can use:

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

at the start of your painting method. It will paint your circles smoother.

Check out: [Drag a painted Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape) as an example for implementing the painting suggestions. In that example it adds a MouseListener to the panel. You want to start with a KeyListener, but the concept of how to implement the class will be the same.