# Java rotating a Polgon deforms it

Tags: java, swing, rotation, polygon, affinetransform

I have written a method, which randomly generates polygon shapes, which then are rotating and moving across the screen. Since I wanted to detect collision with these shapes, I did not rotate them with Graphics2D and instead used AffineTransform to rotate them. But for some reason, certain shapes are getting messed up by the rotation, while others are unaffected. Below is an example with one of the shapes which caused problems.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test extends JLabel{

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Polygon poly;

    Point center;
    Point source[];
    Point dest[];

    JFrame jf;

    public Test() {

        init();
        createPolygon();

        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rotatePoly();
                repaint();
            }});
        timer.start();
    }
    public void rotatePoly() {

        AffineTransform transf = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(2), center.x, center.y);
        transf.transform(source, 0, dest, 0, source.length);

        poly = toPolygon(dest);

    }
    public Polygon toPolygon(Point[] points) {

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            polygon.addPoint(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        }
        return polygon;
    }
    public void createPolygon() {

        Point points[] = new Point[7];

        points[0] = new Point(20, 97);
        points[1] = new Point(82, 70);
        points[2] = new Point(134, 70);
        points[3] = new Point(210, 88);
        points[4] = new Point(210, 106);
        points[5] = new Point(144, 125);
        points[6] = new Point(82, 125);

        source = points;
        dest = points;

        poly = toPolygon(points);

        center = new Point(poly.getBounds().x + poly.getBounds().width / 2, poly.getBounds().y + poly.getBounds().height / 2);

    }
    public void init() {

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(260, 260);

        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(260, 260);
        jf.setContentPane(new JLabel());
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocation((screenSize.width / 2) - (getWidth() / 2), (screenSize.height / 2) - (getHeight() / 2));
        jf.add(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        g2d.drawPolygon(poly);

    }
}
```

If you replace the points with the following lines, the shape mostly stays the same. The shape below is of course symmetrical, however the rotate method did work with other randomly generated and uneven shapes.

```
points[0] = new Point(10, 130);
points[1] = new Point(100, 10);
points[2] = new Point(160, 10);
points[3] = new Point(250, 100);
points[4] = new Point(250, 160);
points[5] = new Point(160, 250);
points[6] = new Point(100, 250);
```

Comment: In `createPolygon()` the source and destination are set to the same array. The documentation for [`AffineTransform::transform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#transform-java.awt.geom.Point2D:A-int-java.awt.geom.Point2D:A-int-int-) states that "If, however, the destination Point2D object for one operation is the same object as the source Point2D object for another operation further down the source array then the original coordinates in that point are overwritten before they can be converted."

Comment: @DavidConrad Ok but how would I change that? I have just tried using points.copy() on both source and dest, but that did not work any better. When I only set the value of source to points and just let dest be it throws a NullPointerException and when I only set the value of source to points but this time set dest = new Point[source.length] it throws an ArrayStoreException.

Comment: Sorry, I see from the answers that that apparently was not the problem.

Comment: Don't extend JLabel for custom painting. Instead you should extend JPanel or JComponent. Also the "Shapes" you want to paint should be contained in an ArrayList. Then the paintComponent() method will iterated through the ArrayList to paint each Shape. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape for a simple example of this approach. This will make it easier for your "hit detection" logic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your AffineTransform.  It returns a transformed shape instead of modifying the coordinates.  I also recommend:

- `JFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` for centering on screen.
- Use `RenderingHints` with Antialiasing on to smooth out the graphics.
- Since Polygon implements Shape, a few locations needed to be retyped.

```
class Text extends JLabel{

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Shape poly;

    Point center;
    Point source[];
    Point dest[];

    JFrame jf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Text();
    }
    public Text() {

        init();
        createPolygon();

        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rotatePoly();
                repaint();
            }});
        timer.start();
    }
    public void rotatePoly() {

        AffineTransform transf = 
        AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(2), center.x, center.y);
        poly = transf.createTransformedShape(poly);

    }
    public Shape toPolygon(Point[] points) {

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            polygon.addPoint(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        }
        return polygon;
    }
    public void createPolygon() {

        Point points[] = new Point[7];

        points[0] = new Point(20, 97);
        points[1] = new Point(82, 70);
        points[2] = new Point(134, 70);
        points[3] = new Point(210, 88);
        points[4] = new Point(210, 106);
        points[5] = new Point(144, 125);
        points[6] = new Point(82, 125);

        source = points;
        dest = points;

        poly = toPolygon(points);

        center = new Point(poly.getBounds().x + poly.getBounds().width / 2, poly.getBounds().y + poly.getBounds().height / 2);

    }
    public void init() {

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(260, 260);

        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(260, 260);
        jf.setContentPane(new JLabel());
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocation((screenSize.width / 2) - (getWidth() / 2), (screenSize.height / 2) - (getHeight() / 2));
        jf.add(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        g2d.draw(poly);

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I know how to rotate the graphics context. However as mentioned in my question, I want to detect collisions with the poligon. I could use a rectangle for that, but that would not be very accurate with certain shapes. I therefore decided to use a polygon, so that I would be able to use the intersects() method of the Polygon class.

Comment: @mousekip OK, I updated my answer with a few suggestions.

Comment: Ah thank you that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mostly caused by using integer coordinates for the polygon.
Instead of accumulating the rotations in the polygon itself, use a variable to hold the angle and calculate a new polygon based on the original one every time the angle is changed. The original polygon is not changed.

I tried to maintain the original code as much as possible<sup>**1**</sup>:

```java
package cfh.test.sf;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PolygonTest extends JLabel{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PolygonTest();
    }
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Polygon poly;
    Shape rotated;
    Point center;
    int angle = 0;

    JFrame jf;

    public PolygonTest() {

        init();
        createPolygon();

        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rotatePoly();
                repaint();
            }});
        timer.start();
    }
    public void rotatePoly() {
        angle += 2;
        AffineTransform transf = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), center.x, center.y);
        rotated = transf.createTransformedShape(poly);
    }
    public Polygon toPolygon(Point[] points) {

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            polygon.addPoint(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        }
        return polygon;
    }
    public void createPolygon() {

        Point points[] = new Point[7];

        points[0] = new Point(20, 97);
        points[1] = new Point(82, 70);
        points[2] = new Point(134, 70);
        points[3] = new Point(210, 88);
        points[4] = new Point(210, 106);
        points[5] = new Point(144, 125);
        points[6] = new Point(82, 125);

        poly = toPolygon(points);
        rotated = poly;

        center = new Point(poly.getBounds().x + poly.getBounds().width / 2, poly.getBounds().y + poly.getBounds().height / 2);

    }
    public void init() {

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(260, 260);

        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(260, 260);
        jf.setContentPane(new JLabel());
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocation((screenSize.width / 2) - (getWidth() / 2), (screenSize.height / 2) - (getHeight() / 2));
        jf.add(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        g2d.draw(rotated);

    }
}
```

<sup>**1** - instead of having an additional shape in a field, I would prefer to create the rotated shape inside `paintComponent`. Not sure if that *conflicts* with the rest of the program (e.g. calculating intersection)</sup>

---

Alternative, not tested: use `Point2D.Float` or `Point2D.Double` instead of `Point` for the coordinates.

Comment: Yes I see, with this method you run zero risk of damaging the polygon permenantly. However since the solution from earlier worked perfectly I will not change my code now due to my own laziness. Also yes I do need the shape to detect collisions via the intersects() method from the Shape class. But thank you for your answer, It will certainly help the next time I do something similar.