# Mouse Collision with JComponent and AWT MouseEvent Problem

Tags: java, swing, awt, collision-detection, collision

So I have a problem with my mouse detection using a object called Ornament that inherits JComponent and I am getting the mouse clicks using java.awt.event.MouseEvent.

The solution me and my group though would be the best is to compare the distance of each ornament to the mouse and if its less than 50 (which is the radius of the ornament) it would do something.

```java
private class ME implements MouseListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i < ORNAMENT_AMOUNT; i++) {
                Ornament current = oh.getOrnament(i);

                int distance = (int)(Math.sqrt(((e.getX() - current.getX()) * (e.getX() - current.getX())) + ((e.getY() - current.getY()) * (e.getY() - current.getY()))));
                
                if(distance <= 50) {
                    System.out.println("CIRCLE CLICKED!");
                    current.reset();
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem that I am getting is that it just does not work how it should. I click in the same spot many times and eventually it will trigger the event on one of the ornaments. Its random and confusing.

Here is the Ornament class

```java
//ornament class to define the game object ornament
public class Ornament extends JComponent{
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int velocity;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    private Random rand;


    public Ornament(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, int velocity) {....}

    public int getY() { return yPos; }
    public int getX() { return xPos; }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {

        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();

        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        graphics.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
        graphics.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    ....

    public void reset() {
        this.yPos = -(int)(Math.random()*500);
        this.xPos = (int)(Math.random()*screenWidth);
        this.velocity += 1;
        update();
    }
}
```

My whole approach to this might be wrong but it seems right in my head so help would be appreciated! :)

*note oh is an objecthandler class I made to run the game loop in a different thread that has an array of ornaments

```java
public class ObjectHandler implements Runnable {

    private int size; 
    private Ornament[] list;

    private GUI game;

    public ObjectHandler(int size, GUI game) {
        ....
        list = new Ornament[size];

        //init object list
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list[i] = new Ornament(game.getFrameX(), game.getFrameY(), game.getStartingVel());
            game.add(list[i]);
        }
    }

    public Ornament getOrnament(int index) { return list[index]; }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            game.loadBackground();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                if(list[i].getY() >= game.getFrameY())
                    list[i].reset();
                else
                    list[i].update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding your `MouseListener`?

Comment: Ornament should be a plain Java getter/setter class.  You create one drawing `JPanel` and draw all your sprites on that `JPanel`.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how Swing drawing works.

Comment: @hfontanez mouse listener is in the constructor of the JFrame addMouseListener(new ME());

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Ill give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: A painting method should never use random logic. You can't control when Swing will repaint a component so you don't want the painting to randomly change. You set the state of the component outside of the painting method. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape for an example that paints shapes and supports hit detection when using the mouse.

Comment: @camickr I am assuming you are referring to the random color I put in there. Will move that to a private variable on the Ornament, thanks.

Comment: In addition, I don't think you would want the `JFrame` to have a single `MouseListener` that then has to interrogate the event object to determine which component triggered the event. Each `Ornament` is a `JComponent` (which is a `Container`) and as such, each can have their own `MouseListener`. This is, in my opinion, the best approach. Each `MouseEvent` produced will tell you which `Ornament` instance it belongs to.

Comment: @hfontanez debating weather or not I want to take that approach or do what Gilbert recommended. Ill try both and see which one works best! Thanks!

Comment: Take this into consideration: If you ever want to add a component to the frame that behaves differently, you will need to complicate the logic of the mouse listener even further. If you contain the logic within the component's own listener, only the listener for the new component is changed. Also, if you ever need to remove the component, code cleanup is a breeze because it is self-contained.

Comment: ALSO.. ask camickr. He is our Java Swing resident expert.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help!
I used Gilbert Le Blanc's method to get this to work.

I removed the JComponent off of the Ornament class and instead created a class that inherits JPanel

```java
ublic class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    
    private Ornament[] objectList;
    ......
    public GamePanel(GUI game) {
        ....
        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener();
        addMouseListener(ml);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }
```

I then added a paint component and rendered each Ornament in the objectList array using a for loop

```java
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            .....
            for(int i = 0; i < objectList.length; i++) {
                Color c = new Color(objectList[i].r, objectList[i].g, objectList[i].b);
                g2.setColor(c);
                g2.fillOval(objectList[i].getX(), objectList[i].getY(), 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
```

Furthemore I added the mouselistener to the JPanel component. Using the same technique for mouse to object collision and it worked!

```java
class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(!gameOver) {
                for(int i = 0; i < objectList.length; i++) {
                    int distance = (int)(Math.sqrt(((e.getX() - objectList[i].getX()) * (e.getX() - objectList[i].getX())) + ((e.getY() - objectList[i].getY()) * (e.getY() - objectList[i].getY()))));
                    
                    if(distance <= 50) {
                        game.incScore();
                        objectList[i].reset();
                    }
                }
            ...
        }
    }
```

Shoutout to hfontanez and Gilbert Le Blanc for the help! :)