# How to combine rectangles?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I am working with the Java Swing library. I have two rectangles of the same width and height and the same coordinates. I want to combine them into one so I can get a cross. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: See [Drag a Painted Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape) for one approach.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a [`new Area(Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Area.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.awt.Shape)) of both rectangles, then [`area1.add(area2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Area.html#add(java.awt.geom.Area)) (add one to the other).

See also the [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) trail of the tutorial.

Comment: var rect1 = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            var rect2 = new Rectangle(x, y, height, width);

            Area a1 = new Area((java.awt.Shape) rect1);
            Area a2 = new Area((java.awt.Shape) rect2);

            a1.add(a2);
            
            Thanks, I managed to combine shapes. But How can I get acces to that shape later ? How can I basscily put it in a variable?

Comment: @KAWFVKe24 You already have the variable, `a1`, what more do you need