# Adding mouseevent to circle

Tags: java, swing, graphics

i'm trying to make an AimTrainer where you click a circle and it makes another appear which I can do but I can not figure out how to make it so when you click a circle it registers a mouseevent. I have no idea where to start. Right now my code just draws circles and they get smaller and smaller over time until they disappear. I want to make my circles clickable. Any help appreciated.

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testingapplication;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
/**
 *
 * @author 18086
 */
public class GameForm2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     
    private ConstantsAndLogic constantsandlogic;
    
    public void UpdateBoard(){
        // Cursor();
        ConstantsAndLogic.circlesize();
         repaint();
         if (ConstantsAndLogic.iDiameterX == 0){
             ConstantsAndLogic.main();
             ConstantsAndLogic.resetdiameter();
         }
     }
    
    public GameForm2 (){
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 50);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        this.setVisible(true);
        constantsandlogic = new ConstantsAndLogic();
        ConstantsAndLogic.main();
   
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(ConstantsAndLogic.iCircleX,ConstantsAndLogic.iCircleY,ConstantsAndLogic.iDiameterX,ConstantsAndLogic.iDiameterY);
        
        System.out.println(ConstantsAndLogic.iCircleX);
        System.out.println(ConstantsAndLogic.iCircleY);
       
   }
    
    public void Cursor() {
        Point cursor = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
 }
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
   TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
           UpdateBoard();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Events are only generated for components. A painted circle is not a component. You need to manage the MouseEvent on the panel to do your processing. Create an ArrayList of circles you want to paint. Then when an MouseEvent is generated for your panel you iterate through the ArrayList to find the circle you clicked on and then you do your processing. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape for an example to get you started. The example allows you to drag a shape.

Comment: Overriding paint of a top level container is generally a bad (and is one of the many reasons why it's generally discouraged to extend from top level container like `JFrame`) - see [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details

Comment: Swing is also not thread safe, so using a `TimerTask` to update the UI is not a good idea.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a common solution

Comment: Your problem basically boils down to [circle hit detection in swing](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+circle+hit+detection&oq=java+swing+circle+hit+detection&aqs=chrome..69i57.5070j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - personally, I'd make use of the `Shape`s API, but your needs might be different