# How to only drag object in JFrame when clicking on it, not around it

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

The goal here is to only be able to drag the circle (rock) around when the mouse clicks on it and I can't seem to figure it out. Right now, I can click anywhere in the frame and be able to move the circle. Any suggestions appreciated!

Here's my main class that has the Jframe, label and my object called rock

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        
        rock = new Rock(0,0, SIZE); 
    
        
        final MyIcon myIcon = new MyIcon(rock, ICON_W, ICON_H);
        final JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(myIcon);
        
        
        myLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                
                rock.mousePoint = e.getPoint();
                if (! myLabel.contains(rock.mousePoint)) {
                    rock.mousePoint = null;
                }   
            }
        });
        
        myLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                
                if (rock.mousePoint != null) {
                    Point lastMousePoint = rock.mousePoint;
                    rock.mousePoint = e.getPoint();
                    double dx = rock.mousePoint.getX() - lastMousePoint.getX();
                    double dy = rock.mousePoint.getY() - lastMousePoint.getY();
                    rock.translate((int) dx, (int) dy);
                    myFrame.repaint();
                    myFrame.pack();
                }
            }
        });
    
        myFrame.repaint();
        myFrame.add(myLabel);
        myFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    
        
    
    }
    static Rock rock;
    //private static Point mousePoint;
    private static final int SIZE = 40;
    private static final int ICON_W = 800;
    private static final int ICON_H = 550;

}
```

This is the rock object class

```
public class Rock implements MovingObject{


    public Rock(int x, int y, int size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = x;
        this.size = size;
        mousePoint = new Point();
        //rock = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, size, size);
    }

    public void translate(int xChange, int yChange) {
        x += xChange;
        y += yChange;
    }
   
   
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2D) {
        
        Ellipse2D.Double rock = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, size, size);
        g2D.fill(rock);
        g2D.draw(rock);
    }
    
    
   // Ellipse2D.Double rock;
    protected Point mousePoint;
    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
}
```

Comment: I think this, `myLabel.contains`, is very strange. I would suggest debugging it. Look at the value of `rock.mousePoint` I think you'll find myLabel.contains more than you expect. I would suggest `myLabel.getBounds().contains()` Though I am not sure about this.

Comment: I dont' even see a JLabel.contains that takes a Point as an argument. Does this code even compile?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I definitely think the myLabel is odd too, I'll debug it more.

Comment: The overall design would appear to be wrong. You attempt to make the Rock a MovingObject which is wrong. The label is the component the moves. The Rock is just an Icon of the label. If you really want to drag a "Shape" that is painted directly on a panel then check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape