# Changing the Behavior of Balls Depending on the Grid They Touch (JAVA Swing)

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a frame that I painted half black and half white with Java Swing's grid methods. And on this frame, there is a white ball that starts moving on the black part and a black ball that starts moving on the white part. I want these balls to bounce back if they touch grids that are the same color as them and paint the grid they touch in the opposite color. I have completed everything except the last feature, but I can't figure out how to implement the last feature in the application.

Interface.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Interface extends JFrame{
    
    private int frameHeight = 637;
    private int frameWidth = 1214;
    
    public Interface() {

        setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
        add(new Core());
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Interface();

    }

}
```

Core.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Core extends JPanel{
    
    int xw = 10, yw = 10, xb = 1000, yb = 400;
    int bounds = 20, gridSize = 20;
    int vxw = 5, vyw = 5, vxb = 5, vyb = 5;
    int rows, columns;

    public Core() {

        rows = getHeight() / gridSize;
        columns = getWidth() / gridSize;
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                System.out.println(getHeight());
                System.out.println(getWidth());
                
                xw += vxw;
                yw += vyw;

                xb -= vxb;
                yb -= vyb;

                if (xw > getWidth() - bounds || xw < 0) {vxw = -vxw;}
                if (yw > getHeight() - bounds || yw < 0) {vyw = -vyw;}
                if (xb > getWidth() - bounds || xb < 0) {vxb = -vxb;}
                if (yb > getHeight() - bounds || yb < 0) {vyb = -vyb;}

                repaint();

            }
            
        });

        timer.start();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2dw = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graphics2D g2db = (Graphics2D) g;
        Graphics2D grid = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        super.paintComponent(g);    
            
            for (int k = 0; k < getWidth(); k += gridSize) {
                for (int z = 0; z < getHeight(); z += gridSize) {
                     
                    grid.drawRect(k, z, gridSize, gridSize);

                     if (k < getWidth() / 2) {
                        grid.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        grid.fillRect(k, z, gridSize, gridSize);
                     } else {
                        grid.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        grid.fillRect(k, z, gridSize, gridSize);

                     }
                }
            }
        

            g2dw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2dw.setColor(Color.white);
            g2dw.fillOval(xw, yw, bounds, bounds);
            //g2d.dispose();

            g2db.setColor(Color.black);
            g2db.fillOval(xb, yb, bounds, bounds);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        

    }

}
```

Example Output:
https://github.com/vnglst/pong-wars

I'm trying to learn how to write a feature that will make the balls bounce when they touch a grid with the same color as them and paint the grid they touch with the opposite color. Any hints or guidance would be much appreciated too, if you don't want to bother with writing Java code.

I tried creating a 2D array that contains 1 or 0 values (1 for white grid, 0 for black) but encountered with IndexBound errors.

Comment: First of all the basic painting logic is incorrect. 1) you only need to cast the Graphics object passed to the paintComponent() method to a Graphics2D object once. 2) you only need to set the rendering hints once 3) You should only invoke super.paintComponent(...) once. Your code only works because the paintComponent() method of the JComponent class doesn't do any painting. Try extending JPanel to see the different. Each call will clear the background so you only ever see the last ball painted.

Comment: Then to do you painting I would create two ArrayLists, one for the tiles and the other for the balls. Each ArrayList would then contain an Object with multiple properties: 1) the Shape and 2) the Color. You would then iterate through the ArrayList to paint the tiles and then paint the balls. In your Timer logic you would update the location of each ball. Then you can use iterate through the "tiles" ArrayList and use the `intersects()` method to see if the ball intersects a tile that is the same color. If so, you change the color of the tile.

Comment: See: [Drag a Painted Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443343/drag-a-painted-shape) for the basic concept of painting Shapes from an ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I fixed the logic errors. But how can I place the square objects into the tiles?

Comment: When you create the Core panel you should pass parameters like: rows, columns, tileSize to the class. Using this information you would then: 1) override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the class to calculate the preferred size based on the parameters and 2) create each ColoredShape object. So, basically your current looping logic in the paintComponent() method is moved to the constructor of your class to create each tile in the ArrayList.

Comment: You can also see [Ball Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872) for an example of painting bouncing balls from an ArrayList. So, you first step would be to convert the code to paint the tiles and balls from two separate ArrayLists. Then you need to modify the Timer logic to handle the intersection of the balls with the tiles, instead of the panel edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to camickr's instructions, there is the Java code:

Core.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Core extends JPanel {

    //Adjusting the starting points of balls and other variables
    protected int xw = Interface.frameWidth / 2 - 40, yw = Interface.frameHeight / 2, xb = Interface.frameWidth / 2 + 40, yb = Interface.frameHeight / 2;
    private int bounds;
    private int rows, columns, tileSize;
    private ArrayList<ColoredShape> tiles;
    private ArrayList<Ball> balls;

    public Core(int rows, int columns, int tileSize) {
        
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
        this.bounds = tileSize / 2;
        this.tiles = new ArrayList<>();
        this.balls = new ArrayList<>();

        // Creating tiles
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                
                int x = j * tileSize;
                int y = i * tileSize;
                Shape rect = new Rectangle(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
                Color color = (j < columns / 2) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
                tiles.add(new ColoredShape(rect, color));

            }
        }

        // Creating balls
        balls.add(new Ball(xw, yw, bounds, Color.WHITE, 10, 3));
        balls.add(new Ball(xb, yb, bounds, Color.BLACK, 10, -3));

        // Animation part
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                moveBalls();
                checkCollision();
                repaint();
            }

        });

        timer.start();
    }

    //Moving balls
    private void moveBalls() {
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            
            ball.setX(ball.getX() + ball.getVx());
            ball.setY(ball.getY() + ball.getVy());
    
            // Bouncing back from walls
            if (ball.getX() > getWidth() - ball.getShape().width || ball.getX() < 0) {
                ball.setVx(-ball.getVx());
            }
            if (ball.getY() > getHeight() - ball.getShape().height || ball.getY() < 0) {
                ball.setVy(-ball.getVy());
            }

        }
    }

    private void checkCollision() {
        
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            
            for (ColoredShape tile : tiles) {
                
                if (ball.getShape().getBounds().intersects(tile.getShape().getBounds())) {
                    
                    if (ball.getColor().equals(tile.getColor())) {
                        
                        tile.setColor(ball.getColor().equals(Color.WHITE) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                        
                        // Calculating the angle of incidence
                        double tileCenterX = tile.getShape().getBounds2D().getCenterX();
                        double tileCenterY = tile.getShape().getBounds2D().getCenterY();
                        double ballCenterX = ball.getShape().getCenterX();
                        double ballCenterY = ball.getShape().getCenterY();

                        double angle = Math.atan2(ballCenterY - tileCenterY, ballCenterX - tileCenterX);

                        // Adjusting velocity based on angle of incidence
                        if (Math.abs(angle) < Math.PI / 4 || Math.abs(angle) > 3 * Math.PI / 4) {
                            // Adjusting x velocity
                            ball.setVx(-ball.getVx());
                        } else {
                            // Adjusting y velocity
                            ball.setVy(-ball.getVy());
                        }

                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Drawing tiles
        for (ColoredShape tile : tiles) {
            g2d.setColor(tile.getColor());
            g2d.fill(tile.getShape());
        }

        // Drawing balls
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            g2d.setColor(ball.getColor());
            g2d.fill(ball.getShape());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(columns * tileSize, rows * tileSize);
    }

}
```

Interface.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Interface extends JFrame {

    protected static int frameHeight = 637;
    protected static int frameWidth = 637;
    private int tileSize = 30;

    public Interface() {

        setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
        add(new Core(frameHeight / tileSize, frameWidth / tileSize, tileSize)); // Rows, Columns, TileSize
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Interface();
    }

}

class ColoredShape {
    
    private Shape shape;
    private Color color;

    public ColoredShape(Shape shape, Color color) {
        
        this.shape = shape;
        this.color = color;

    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}

class Ball {
    
    private Ellipse2D.Double shape;
    private Color color;
    private int vx;
    private int vy;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int diameter, Color color, int vx, int vy) {
        
        this.shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, diameter, diameter);
        this.color = color;
        this.vx = vx;
        this.vy = vy;

    }

    public Ellipse2D.Double getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getVx() {
        return vx;
    }

    public void setVx(int vx) {
        this.vx = vx;
    }

    public int getVy() {
        return vy;
    }

    public void setVy(int vy) {
        this.vy = vy;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return (int) shape.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        shape.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return (int) shape.y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        shape.y = y;
    }
    
}
```

There was a logic error in your code, I fixed it:

- When the balls touched a square, both the x and y direction variables changed direction, which prevented a realistic collision, the balls would collide in a symmetrical pattern after a certain period of time in the same way forever.
  I fixed it by calculating the collision angle as in the example code you provided.
- Still has a repetitive infrastructure where I don't randomize the starting directions of the balls, but it can easily be fixed.